# RE:Outliner animation realtime update?

Tags: animation

Hei, i'm working on a mograph project in blender and i'm wondering if anyone knows a way to get the outliner to updat in realtime during play back? Currently if i scrub an animation or play frame by frame (by tapping left or right key) it will show just fine, how ever any time i simply play the animation (alt+a) it will only update this information on the frame i pause on.

Comment: I'm very curious as to why a UI control is that important to you? As there is a great deal of effort put into the compute of the actual render, which is what most people using blender would consider the critical output. I would really like to know more about your usage context, do you mind explaining this a little more inside of your question?

Comment: Sure, in this case the project is using baked f-curves from audio to control the response of instanced piano keys. Having organised the notes in the outliner into groups to keep track of everything in sequence the visibility of each object in effect shows when that key is active and responding to a pitch. Hence it would be handy to be able to see this in realtime as it would play a bit like a score sheet as a result, it's not a big problem as it does respond when scrubbing.